# JavaFX TranslateTransition doesn't go to the point definied

Tags: java, javafx, transition

I want my blue circle go from one light blue circle to another, but only does half.

[image]

The coordinates appear being the same:

```
initial_lightblue: 211.7,230.5
blue: 193.7,239.1
final_lighblue: 193.7,239.1
```

My code

```
TranslateTransition transition = new TranslateTransition();
transition.setToX(c.getX());
transition.setToY(c.getY());
transition.setNode(view);
transition.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
transition.play();
```

Any sugestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From documentation

> **TranslateTransition** : This Transition creates a move/translate animation that spans its duration. This is done by updating the
>   translateX, translateY and translateZ variables of the node at regular
>   interval.

So it's going to use the translate properties in order to relocate the actual node inside your pane. With that being said if you locate your node at x=50 and y=50 by setting its layoutX and layoutY properties their translation values will be 0, so if you actually try to set the end coordinates of the TranslateTransition to be ex. x = 100 y = 100 then its going to move your Node to the x = 150 and y = 150 and not to the (x,y) = (100,100) cause its going to change the translation property (x and y) from 0 to 100 which will move the node eventually to (x,y) = 150,150.

With that been said here is an example :

```
import javafx.animation.Interpolator;
import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application {

    private Circle c1;
    private Circle c2;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        AnchorPane pane = new AnchorPane();

        // Set only the radius
        c1 = new Circle(5);
        c1.setFill(Color.BLUE);

        // Let's translate the c1 to the location we want
        c1.setTranslateX(50);
        c1.setTranslateY(60);

        // The same for circle2
        c2 = new Circle(5);
        c2.setFill(Color.RED);

        c2.setTranslateX(120);
        c2.setTranslateY(200);

        pane.getChildren().addAll(c1, c2);

        pane.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            startAnimation();
        });

        stage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 400, 500));
        stage.show();
    }

    private void startAnimation() {
        TranslateTransition transition = new TranslateTransition();
        transition.setNode(c1);
        transition.setToX(c2.getTranslateX());
        transition.setToY(c2.getTranslateY());
        transition.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
        transition.play();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**P.S** : In your code example you are referring to circles but you call `c.getX()` to actually take the x of the circle, that is quite strange cause the Circle class doesn't have method `getX()` I am quessing you are referreing to getCenterX() or those are not Circles .

Comment: I noticed that when I do setTranslateX and Y instead of set X and Y on the constructor of the circle that the representation is different. Thanks!